# Specifying Validator inside JSF 1.2 custom component

Tags: java, lifecycle, validation, custom-component, jsf-1.2

I have defined by custom Validator (implements javax.faces.validator.Validator interface and defined in faces-config). I need my custom component to call this validator within my component code ( Renderer class).
I want to make my xhtml as clean as possible and don't want to invoke the validator separately in my xhtml by embedding

```
<f:validator validatorId='xx' />
```

within my component tag. 
Just like how I can implement

```
getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue)
```

within my Renderer to handle conversion, can I do something similar to handle validation within Renderer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to be done at the UI component level, not at the renderer level. Your custom input component must surely already extend [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html), otherwise you've many other (future) problems and/or you'll waste time in writing repeated code. If your custom input component extends `UIInput`, then you can just add the `Validator` by the inherited [`UIInput#addValidator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#addValidator%28javax.faces.validator.Validator%29) method in for example the component's constructor.

```
public MyCustomInputComponent() {
    addValidator(new MyCustomValidator());
}
```

The already-implemented [`UIInput#validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#validate%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method will do all the conversion, validation and message handling automagically.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. Just curious why getConvertedValue() was exposed in Renderer to handle conversion but not addValidator to handle validation?

Comment: Conversion is more a rendering job (takes place during encoding HTML markup and during decoding HTTP params) and is logically the responsibility of the `Renderer`. Validation does not take place during rendering and is more specific to input components of `UIInput` family. Validation takes place during validations phase. Validation does not manipulate the values for input/output. You can have more than one validators, but not more than one converters. Well, I think this JSF design decision makes fully sense.

Comment: Not to lengthen further the question, I need to dynamically add/determine the Validator ( eg. US vs. Canadian Zipcode Validator based on previous inputText value(captures State/Provine" information). How can I call addValidator() dynamically?

Comment: Create another validator which delegates further to the right validator based on the "previous value".

Comment: Are you suggesting retrieving the 'state/province' value entered from Context object in the first validator's validate() method and calling the respective zipcode Validators?

Comment: I have no idea how to retrieve "previous value" as you didn't tell anything about how your component tree is composed. I was under the impression that you already know how to obtain "previous value" (how else would you be able to determine the validator?). I am just suggesting that you can use a single validator for this which in turn delegates the job further to the proper validator depending on "previous value". This way you can continue using the `addValidator()` in constructor approach. Feel free to ask a new question if you stucks, this is offtopic.